# Can rectangle be split in rows and columns?

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics, drawing, rectangles

```
          private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen mypen = default(Pen);
        mypen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 3);
        mypen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;
        //For Dash Line in Rectangle 
        Pen mypen1 = default(Pen);
        mypen1 = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Blue, 1);
        mypen1.DashStyle![enter image description here][2] = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;

        //Pen mypen2 =default(Pen);
        //mypen2 = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow, 3);
        //mypen2.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;

        //Pen mypen3 = default(Pen);
        //mypen3 = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Violet, 1);
        //mypen3.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;

        L1 = Rect1LT.X + 5;
        T1 = Rect1LT.Y + 5;
        W1 = Rect1RB.X - Rect1LT.X;
        H1 = Rect1RB.Y - Rect1LT.Y;


        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(mypen, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(L1, T1, W1, H1));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(mypen1, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(L1, T1, W1, H1));

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1LT.X, Rect1LT.Y, 10, 10));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1RT.X, Rect1RT.Y, 10, 10));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1LB.X, Rect1LB.Y, 10, 10));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1RB.X, Rect1RB.Y, 10, 10));

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1LT);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1RT);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1LB);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1RB);

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1T.X, Rect1T.Y, 10, 10));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1R.X, Rect1R.Y, 10, 10));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1B.X, Rect1B.Y, 10, 10));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(Rect1L.X, Rect1L.Y, 10, 10));

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1T);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1R);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1B);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, Rect1L);

        DataGridView dg1 = new DataGridView();


        //while (!exit)
        //{
        //    var time = GetTime();
        //    Update(time);
        //    Render(time);
        //}


    }
```

I want to Divide Rectangle in Rows and Columns and Size of Rows and Column can be changeable at runtime? and No of Rows and Columns also can be changeable? I don't want to split whole rectangle I just want to divide them in rectangle.

Comment: What your code is supposed to do? What kind of values are stored in the variables Rect1T, Rect1B, Rect1L, Rect1R?

Comment: Of course you can do that but you will need two loops and will need to calculate the rect parms from your input.. Your code only seems to use 4 hard coded rects..

Comment: I am drawing Rectangle on panel with Simple Background. I Want that Rectangle to be divided into several cells like cells in Data Grid View.

Comment: Is your problem resolved now?

Comment: Yeah Dear, Thanks to you, it's been solved...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simplfied example:

```
int cols = 7; int rows = 11;

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle Rect = // your Rectangle!

    Rectangle pRect = Rect;  // panel2.ClientRectangle;
    float width = 1f * pRect.Width / cols;
    float height = 1f * pRect.Height / rows;

    using (Pen pen = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Blue, 1))
    {
      pen.DashStyle = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.DashStyle.Dash;

      for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
         for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
         {
            RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(pRect.X + c * width, pRect.Y + r * height, 
                                             width, height);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Coral, rect);
            // e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
         }

        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 
             pRect.X + c * width, pRect.Y, pRect.X + c * width, pRect.Y + pRect.Height);
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 
             pRect.X, pRect.Y + r * height, pRect.X + pRect.Width, pRect.Y + r * height);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 
                                 pRect.X, pRect.Y, pRect.Width - 1, pRect.Height - 1);

    }
}
```

Note a few changes:

- The border color and the fill color must not be the same.
- The fill must come first or it will overwrite the border
- I work with floats to fill the panel completely; if the cols and rows don't divide into the panel/rectangle size evenly, the recangles will not all have the same sizes ..
- At first I have ignored your `DashStyle`. If you want to have a `DashStyle` you must completely change your plan! The reason is that if you draw Rectangles in a grid you..

  - ..either have them overlapping and then the dashes will get in each others way. There is a `DashOffset` parameter but I don't think it can be twisted to make it work over any grid.
  - ..or you need to draw the rectangles inside the grid cells but then they will be twice a thick and the patterns still will disturb each other.

Instead you simply draw only a few lines as shown!

Here is my example with Dashes:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: you did this for Panel but I want to do this splitting work into Rectangle.  I want cells in rectangle like we have In Data Grid View.

Comment: Thanks Dear.Working Good but is there any way we can make this Dynamic. Resizeable at runtime?

Comment: Since it is all happening in the Paint event ii is dynamic already. All you need to do is change the values for the cols, rows or the Rectangle and then call panel1.Invalidate()..